# If $|R|=p$ where $p$ is prime, then its additive structure is cyclic. Moreover, every non-zero element in $R$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring. Is the following statement true ? If $|R|=p$ where $p$ is prime, then its additive structure is cyclic. Moreover, every non-zero element in $R$ has a multiplicative inverse.

I suspect it is true but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. There is only one abelian group (indeed group) up to isomorphism of order $p$, it's the cyclic group by Lagrange's theorem. Now the multiplication is completely determined as the usual multiplication mod $p$ from the ring axioms
e.g. $m. n = (1 + \cdots +1).(1 + \cdots +1)$ (where the first has $m$ 1's and the second has $n$ 1's), and distributivity along with the identity law tellls you this equals $mn$ mod $p$.

Since every nonzero element has an inverse in the usual multiplication mod $p$, then this is true here too.

Comment: How do we know the additive structure is cyclic when the order of the group is prime? Why is cannot be multiplicative structure is cyclic?

Comment: This answer is valid for the case when $R$ has *unit*. Otherwise there is another example, the zero ring on $\Bbb Z_p$, in which every product is $0$.

Comment: Usually having a ring includes having the one [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring) or [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory)

Comment: Does it has something to do with this theorem ? The characteristic of domain is either zero or prime. By the way, how do we rephrase this theorem into if-then statement?

Comment: Take a nonzero element of your ring (which exists, e.g. $1 \neq 0$ if we assume the ring has a unit. Call your chosen element $x$. The subset $<x> = \{ n.x | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a subgroup of the additive group of your ring. By Lagrange's theorem its order must divide $|R| = p$. But It can't have only one elemnet as it includes at least $0$ and $x$. Therefore the subgroup is the whole group, so $R$ is cyclic, generated by $x$.

Comment: @Tom Harris: I'm not quite undestand your argument of every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: My argument says that the additive structure of the ring \textit{completely determines} the multiplicative structure (if we assume there is a 1). That is I have really shown that any ring with $|R|=p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Since isomorphic rings are essentially the same, and every non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has a multiplicative inverse, the same is true in $R$.

Comment: @TomHarris: So in this statement, there is only one group which satisfies it, that is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $p$ is prime?

Comment: Yes that's correct.